# SQL Server 2017 Express Edition firewall install issue

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

Im currently trying to install this in the SQL server 2017 setup, but I get a warning from windows firewall stating: The Windows Firewall is enabled. Make sure the appropriate ports are open to enable remote access. I`ve seen videos where your suppose to change the ports in the management studio, but I heard that your suppose to install SQL before you install management studio.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017) at Microsoft Docs